# Using Grunt and rsync to sync remote folder with a local folder

Tags: deployment, ssh, gruntjs, web-deployment, rsync

I've successfully installed Grunt Rsync https://github.com/jedrichards/grunt-rsync and had  success 'syncing' a local folder to a remote folder.

```
rsync: {
    options: {
        args: ["--verbose"],
        recursive: true
    },
    stage: {
        options: {
            src: "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/barestrap-wp/library/uploads",
            dest: "shared/library/uploads",
            host: "barestrap@host.com",
            syncDestIgnoreExcl: true
        }
    }
},
```

The success response in terminal is:

```
Shell command was: rsync /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/barestrap-wp/library/uploads barestrap@host.com:shared/library --rsh ssh --recursive --delete --verbose
```

My "problem" is that this overwrites the "uploads" folder in the SSH host completely, i.e. `barestrap@host.com:shared/library/uploads` gets deleted. I'm not sure how to remove `--delete` from the options.

What I'm trying to do is 1) make sure that the SSH uploads folder contains all the files from the local environment, **and** 2) that the local environment contains all the files from the remote SSH environment.

This grunt task is partially successful in the first goal, but I'm unsure of how to achieve the second– in other words:

`$ rsync barestrap@host.com:shared/library  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/barestrap-wp/library/uploads`

Any insights are very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your culprit is the syncDestIgnoreExcl: true setting in your options.  From the conversation had in Issue #32 reported to grunt-rsync, that setting needs to be false to keep your destination folder from purging files that do not exist in your source directory.